# Is prepwork a real word? What is the proper form if so?

Tags: nouns, is-it-a-word

Is **prepwork** a real word? What about any of these variations: **prep-work** or **prep work**? I cannot find any of those in a dictionary.

Comment: 'Prep' is often used as an abbreviation for 'preparation' or 'preparatory', so 'prep. work' is a phrase rather than a single word.

Comment: "Prep" is still somewhat informal but is widely used, and it is recognized by most native English speakers.  It is normally spelled without the terminating period.

Comment: 'Prepwork 'is a jargon word ( terminology of a special activity or group) at this time. It seems to have developed from *'groundwork';  preparation made beforehand.* 'Prepwork' usage hasn't become  popular enough to be included in a dictionary yet.

Comment: There is also potential confusion; as [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/prep) says, 'prep' has long been used as an informal noun in its own right: << _prep2_ [noun] 
informal 
1 British mass noun: (in an independent school) schoolwork that is set to be done outside normal school hours. >>

Comment: And don't forget that "prep" with regard to the culinary arts has been in use for probably a century.

Answer (score 7):

I have not been able to find "prepwork" written as a single word in any dictionary I checked (and I checked a number of dictionaries, including the OED). However, several dictionaries list "prep" as an adjective:

> *adj.*
>   Preparatory: *a college prep course; did extensive prep work for the interview.*
>   <sub>American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. (Via [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/prep))</sub>

So, if we go by what the dictionary says, "prep work" (with a space) is correct.

---

Looking at usage, some people will write it instead as one word, probably by analogy with other words, such as homework and artwork. Here are some examples:

- [Garden 2015: Prepwork!](http://themetzfamilyadventures.blogspot.com/2015/04/garden-2015-prepwork.html)
- [I started Vloging with AppAcademy’s prepwork, but Inspired by Freecodecamp](https://medium.com/@amanze.ogbonna/i-started-vloging-with-appacademy-s-prepwork-but-inspired-by-freecodecamp-254e1876838c)
- [Real Food Challenge Prepwork Day 5 – Mainport CrossFit](http://www.mainportcrossfit.com/real-food-challenge-prepwork-day-5/)

(It's also worth noting that there is a "personal research assistant" called [PrepWork](https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/prepwork), which had some hits when I searched. If it's CamelCased, it probably refers to this.)

Comment: Additional: [ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prep+work%2Cprep-work%2Cprepwork&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2018&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cprep%20work%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bprep%20work%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPrep%20work%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPrep%20Work%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPREP%20WORK%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprep%20-%20work%3B%2Cc0) shows one hyphenated instance and no instances as a single word.

Comment: I have heard this term uttered fairly often, but obviously hard to say if it was *prep work* or *prepwork*!

Answer (score 0):

'Prepwork 'is a jargon word ( terminology of a special activity or group) at this time. It seems to have developed from 'groundwork'; preparation made beforehand. 'Prepwork' usage hasn't become popular enough to be included in a dictionary yet. [Source](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/443713/is-prepwork-a-real-word-what-is-the-proper-form-if-so/443772#comment-1066016)

Comment: and if there is no citation for your answer it would be best to delete and place same in comments.

Comment: You don't deserve upvotes for simply copying a comment, especially when it's wrong. Prepwork isn't jargon because it's just a generic word, it's not limited to any field like jargon would be.

Comment: -1. A citation should a link to reputable website, not a link to a comment on this page!

Comment: What citation??

Comment: @user234461 the provided link is just to a comment above

Comment: @k1eran aaahh, now it's a "provided link", not a "citation"?